# How to pass an Instant start, end date as @RequestParam

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

How do I pass a **start date** and **end date** in the `@RequestParam` which are of type `java.time.Instant`?

Currently, I have a created a sample endpoint with this logic below:

```
@GetMapping("sample")
public void sample(@RequestParam("from") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) Instant startDate,
                   @RequestParam("to") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) Instant endDate) {
    // custom logic ...
}
```

But this doesn't work when I pass the start date and end date in the `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

For example:

`http://localhost:port/sample?from=2019-10-10&to=2019-10-15`

I'm getting the below error:

```
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.Instant'.
```

Also the problem is that when I've entity created at yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss how can I ignore the seconds so when I pass date and hours only it will display the result.

Answer (score 4):

Replace `DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE` by `DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME`.

The default time format that Instant expects : `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX`

The code below :

```
@GetMapping("sample")
public void sample(@RequestParam("from") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) Instant startDate,
                   @RequestParam("to") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) Instant endDate) {
    System.out.println("Start date :" + startDate);
    System.out.println("Start date :" + endDate);
}
```

Tested with this data:

```
http://localhost:8081/sample?from=2010-01-01T12:00:00.000Z&to=2010-01-02T12:00:00.000Z
```

Output:

```
Start date: 2010-01-01T12:00:00Z
End date: 2010-01-02T12:00:00Z
```

This should work.

Comment: This doesn't work, bro.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a proper DateTime format to provide the capability of handling timezone for you, I suggest you use the following pattern:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX") Date myDate
```

It's a common ISO DATE_TIME Format and you can easily convert it to Instant afterward.

e.g. "2000-10-31T01:30:00.000-05:00"

Answer (score 1):

Your date strings conform to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format for a date. Therefore, you should use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) as the type i.e.

```
RequestParam("from") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) LocalDate startDate,
            @RequestParam("to") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) LocalDate endDate)
```

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html) is an overview of the `java.time` types.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` the date format that your want.

```
@RequestParam("from") @DateTimeFormat(iso = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                                      Instant startDate, 
@RequestParam("to") @DateTimeFormat(iso = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") 
                                    Instant endDate)
```

Comment: Use iso format in your API, never some format with custom  pattern.